# Pine Script plot MACD line and signal line on chart

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

In my tradingview strategy I would like to plot the MACD macdLine and signalLine ontop of my chart.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/

//@version=5
strategy('MACD',
   overlay=true,
   process_orders_on_close=true,
   default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity,
   initial_capital=1000,
   default_qty_value=100)

[macdLine, signalLine, histLine] = ta.macd(close, 12, 26, 9)
plot(macdLine, color=color.blue)
plot(signalLine, color=color.orange)
```

When the overlay attribute of my strategy is set to true, the lines are not plotted ontop of my chart. If it is set to false, it adds the MACD lines and everything is fine.

How can I draw them in overlay=true ontop of my chart?

Answer (score 1):

With overlay=true your MACD lines are plotted, but you don't see it because your chart is certainly at another scale.